# Sort Algorithm Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Right now i'm struggeling with a basic algorithm, that shall sort a linked list. I have two additional linked lists (in the beginning empty), in which i can copy the Integer Objects of the first linkedlist.

My problem is, that all of my tries simply doesn't work. In the copied example at the bottom, it goes through both of the while loops, but i don't know how to loop everything, until everything is sorted in the third linked list (zug3.zug3). Also i shall compare the actual smallest value of zug1 to the smallest of zug2 and then continue sorting in the list where the value is smaller. That is not possible at the start of sorting, because if i wanna getSmallest() of an empty List, it will get a null pointer exception.

I'm tryin this now since three days with different, for-loops, while-loops, if-else sentences but i don't find out, how to make it work accurate.

Please help!

Example of the Programm:

```
public class Abstellgleis {

LinkedList<Integer> zug1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();


void initialize() {
    for (int i = 0; i <15;i++) {
        Random zahl = new Random();
        int integer = zahl.nextInt(15);
        zug1.add(integer);
    }   
}
public void wagenAnkoppeln(int i) {
    zug1.addFirst(i);
}
int wagenAbkoppeln() {
    int waggonNummer = zug1.getFirst();
    zug1.removeFirst();
    return waggonNummer;
}

int getSmallest() {
    int smallest = zug1.size();
    for( int i =1; i <zug1.size()-1; i++)
    {
        if(zug1.get(i) < smallest )
        {
            //int smallest = integers.get(Oedipus);
            smallest = zug1.get(i);

        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

}

```
public class Rangiergleis {


LinkedList<Integer> zug2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();


void waggonAnkoppeln(int i) {
    zug2.addFirst(i);
}


int waggonAbkoppeln() {
    int waggonNummer = zug2.getFirst();
    zug2.removeFirst();
    return waggonNummer;
}


int getSmallest() {
    int smallest = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < zug2.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (zug2.get(i) < smallest) {
            smallest=zug2.get(i);
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

}

```
public class Zuggleis {

LinkedList<Integer> zug3 = new LinkedList<Integer>();

void waggonAnkoppeln(int i) {
    zug3.addLast(i);
}
```

}

```
public class Steuerung {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Abstellgleis zug1 = new Abstellgleis();
    zug1.initialize();


    Rangiergleis zug2 = new Rangiergleis();


    Zuggleis zug3 = new Zuggleis();


    System.out.println("Abstellgleis:" + zug1.zug1);
    System.out.println("Rangiergleis: " + zug2.zug2);
    System.out.println("Abstellgleis: " + zug3.zug3);


        while (!zug1.zug1.isEmpty()) {


                if (zug1.zug1.getFirst() != zug1.getSmallest()) {
                    zug2.waggonAnkoppeln(zug1.zug1.getFirst());
                    System.out.println("Vom Abstellgleis wurde Wagen " + 
                            zug1.zug1.getFirst() + " aufs Rangiergleis bewegt");
                    zug1.zug1.removeFirst();
                }
                else if (zug1.zug1.getFirst() == zug1.getSmallest()) {
                    zug3.waggonAnkoppeln(zug1.zug1.getFirst());
                    System.out.println(zug1.zug1.getFirst() + "wurde aufs Zuggleis bewegt");
                    zug1.zug1.removeFirst();    
                }

                System.out.println("Abstellgleis:" + zug1.zug1);
                System.out.println("Rangiergleis: " + zug2.zug2);
                System.out.println("Zuggleis: " + zug3.zug3);


        }

        while (!zug2.zug2.isEmpty()) {


            if (zug2.zug2.getFirst() != zug2.getSmallest()) {
                zug1.wagenAnkoppeln(zug2.zug2.getFirst());
                System.out.println("Vom Rangiergleis wurde Wagen " + 
                        zug2.zug2.getFirst() + " aufs Abstellgleis bewegt");
                zug2.zug2.removeFirst();
            }
            else if (zug2.zug2.getFirst() == zug2.getSmallest()) {
                zug3.waggonAnkoppeln(zug2.zug2.getFirst());
                System.out.println(zug2.zug2.getFirst() + " wurde vom Rangiergleis aufs Zuggleis bewegt");
                zug2.zug2.removeFirst();


            }
            System.out.println("Abstellgleis:" + zug1.zug1);
            System.out.println("Rangiergleis: " + zug2.zug2);
            System.out.println("Zuggleis: " + zug3.zug3);

        }
        if (zug1.zug1.isEmpty()) {

            while (!zug2.zug2.isEmpty())

                if (zug2.zug2.getFirst() != zug2.getSmallest()) {
                    zug1.wagenAnkoppeln(zug2.zug2.getFirst());
                    System.out.println("Vom Abstellgleis wurde Wagen " + 
                            zug2.zug2.getFirst() + " aufs Rangiergleis bewegt");
                    zug2.zug2.removeFirst();
                }
                else if (zug2.zug2.getFirst() == zug2.getSmallest()) {
                    zug3.waggonAnkoppeln(zug2.zug2.getFirst());
                    System.out.println(zug2.zug2.getFirst() + "wurde aufs Zuggleis bewegt");
                    zug2.zug2.removeFirst();    
                }
            System.out.println("Abstellgleis:" + zug1.zug1);
            System.out.println("Rangiergleis: " + zug2.zug2);
            System.out.println("Zuggleis: " + zug3.zug3);
        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: Your `getSmallest` methods in `Abstellgleis` and `Rangiergleis` don’t look right. In the first you start by setting `smallest` to `zug1.size()`. First time when the size is 15 this is probably fine, but as the Zug grows shorter, there may come a point when the size is smaller than the smallest element, and then your method will give the wrong result. In `Rangiergleis` you are initializing to 100, that’s sounder. In both methods you are missing the last element. `i <zug1.size()-1` should be either `i < zug1.size()` or `i <= zug1.size()-1` (the former would be conventional).

Comment: In order to be precise about how your program misbehaves, could you give sample list before and after sorting? Also quote precisely any error messages you see (if any).

Comment: Thanks alot! Now everything works out perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getSmallest` methods in `Abstellgleis` and `Rangiergleis` don’t look right. In the first you start by setting `smallest` to `zug1.size()`. First time when the size is 15 this is probably fine, but as the Zug grows shorter, there may come a point when the size is smaller than the smallest element, and then your method will give the wrong result. In `Rangiergleis` you are initializing to 100, that’s sounder. In both methods you are missing the last element. For example in `Abstellgleis.getSmallest()`:

```
    for( int i =1; i <zug1.size()-1; i++)
```

This is in fact missing both the first and the last element. Elements are indexed 0 through `zug1.size() - 1`, so it should be one of the two following:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < zug1.size(); i++) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= zug1.size() - 1; i++) {
```

The former would be conventional. If you are sure there is at least one wagon in the train, you may of course initialize `smallest` to `zug1.get(0)` and the have the loop run from 1 (this could have been what you intended).

In `Rangiergleis.getSmallest()` your loop runs from 0 as it should, but is missing the last element in the same way as in `Abstellgleis`.